# Where is the error in this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got only partial credit for this exam question. I am trying to figure out why.

$$y''+3y'-18y =0$$
$$y(0)=5$$
$$y'(0)=6$$

This is a differential equation of second order with constants coefficient.

so 
$$
y=c_1e^{-6t}+c_2e^{3t}
$$

After doing the calculations I got that $c_1=-1$ and $c_2=6$

That is wrong. But I have double checked my math but can't find the error. Where is it?!

Comment: We're not going to be able to find your error until you show us your work.

Comment: the error is the my $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not correct.

Comment: $y(0)=c_1 +c_2=5$ and $y'(0)=-6c_1+3c_2=6$, how did you calculate $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: What he means is we don't see where you made your mistake in solving the system of equations you obtain using the initial conditions

Comment: "After doing the calculations I got ...". Clearly there is an error somewhere in those calculations. If you want a more specific answer, you have to _show_ those calculations so someone can point out where they went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of your differential equations is
$$
f(t) = c_1 e^{-6t} + c_2 e^{3t} \, .
$$

Applying the initial conditions $f(0)=5$ and $f'(0)=6$ you immediately obtain
$$
f(t)=e^{-6t} + 4 e^{3t} \, .
$$